# Why is mysqli_data_seek not working?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am looping through results to populate a dropdown in a HTML form.  The first time it works fine, and works as expected.  However, when I try to use the msqli_data_seek to reset it, so I can loop through it again, it does not work.

```
<tr>
   <td>
      <select width="2" id="element1" name="element1">
         <option value="NULL" selected="selected"></option>
<?          while ($element = mysqli_fetch_array($element_query))
               echo '<option value="' . $element['element_id'] . '" >' . $element['type'] .    '</option>'; ?>
      </select>
   </td>

   <td>
      <select width="2" id="element2" name="element2"> 
         <option value="NULL" selected="selected"></option>
<?          mysqli_data_seek($element,0);
            while ($element = mysqli_fetch_array($element_query))
               echo '<option value="' . $element['element_id'] . '" >' . $element['type'] . '</option>'; ?>
      </select>
   </td>
</tr>
```

If I replace `mysqli_data_seek($element,0);` with `$element_query = mysqli_query($link, $element_query_raw);` it works.

Comment: Is `$element_query` the result?

Comment: Not helpful.  If no one would ever need it, then why would such a function exist?

Comment: Legacy purposes. Plus most of the PHP "standard library" is misguided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to call mysqli_data_seek() on the result set, not on the array for a single row. Just change the first parameter and you should be all set:

```
mysqli_data_seek($element_query, 0);
```